# Jetpack Compose - Change default Visible % in ModalBottomSheetLayout

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a `ModalBottomSheetLayout` with a list of items in my Compose view, which can be showed by some UI interaction.

By default, when `bottomSheetState.show()` is called, the visible ratio for the BottomSheet is 50%. However, this is not ideal from a UX perspective as the user will have to physically pull up the bottom sheet to see all the contents in the list.

Extremely frustrating is the fact that `bottomSheetState.show()` does *not* take in any parameters, and that the 50% value seems to be hard coded in. According to the declaration in `androix.compose.material`:

```
suspend fun show() {
    val targetValue =
        if (isHalfExpandedEnabled) HalfExpanded
        else Expanded
    animateTo(targetValue = targetValue)
}
```

I would like to instead show a custom value, say 75%, when the bottom sheet is showed, but so far I haven't found a way to do so. Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you can make it 75% visible but you can show it expanded

```
bottomSheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up using.